# R: matching numbers and letters

Tags: r, string

If I have a string like
`"F G123"`
how can I get `"FG"` by matching letters and `123` by matching numbers?

Comment: This is not very clear.  Please describe further the process of arriving at your desired result.  Also an example with a few different strings would be better than just one so that people can effectively test their answers first

Comment: `gsub("\\D", "", "F G123")` and  `gsub("\\d", "", "F G123")` probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with `regexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
x <- 'F G123' #string
x1 <- gsub(' ','',x) #remove spaces

m <- regexpr('[0-9]+', x1 ) #find indices of digits
> regmatches(x1 , m)        #use indices to fetch the digits
[1] "123"


m <- regexpr('[A-Z]+', x1 ) #find indices of Upper Case letters
> regmatches(x1 , m)        #use indices to fetch letters
[1] "FG"
```